# Unexpected behaviour of DATEPART

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Script that lists dates and week number of date:

```
DECLARE @initDate DATE = '2014-01-01';
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '2014-12-31';

WITH dates (date, week)
     AS (SELECT @initDate               date,
                Datepart(ww, @initDate) week
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(ww, 1, t.date),
                Datepart(ww, t.date)
         FROM   dates t
         WHERE  t.date < @endDate)
SELECT dates.date,
       dates.week
FROM   dates
```

The first three rows are:

```
date:       week number
----------  -----------
2014-01-01  1
2014-01-08  1
2014-01-15  2
.....       ..
.....       ..
```

I guess it should be 2 for the second row and 3 for the first, isn't it?
Is it some kind of bug in `DATEPART`? Even if something is depends on first day of the year, first row date differs from second on one week with any settings.

Could you clarify this, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of `Recursive CTE` not because of `Datepart`.

In the Recursive part of CTE `week` is still holding the previous week not the new `date` that generated in recursive part

Try changing your query like this.

```
DECLARE @initDate DATE = '2014-01-01';
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '2014-12-31';

WITH dates (date, week)
     AS (SELECT @initDate               date,
                Datepart(ww, @initDate) week
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(ww, 1, t.date),
                Datepart(ww, Dateadd(ww, 1, t.date))
         FROM   dates t
         WHERE  t.date < @endDate)
SELECT dates.date,
       dates.week
FROM   dates
```